# display username and password value in a text on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to ask and discuss with you for a problem in javascript, i want to display username and password input value on a innerHTML text , but on text   it shows only undefined and  no any other  value , any solution for this ?
is this possible ?
i tried many method but no one works
Thanks so much who helps me  with any solution

```js
let flex = document.querySelector(".flex");
let user = document.getElementById("text1").value;
let pass = document.getElementById("text2").value;
let submit = document.getElementById("submit");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
submit.addEventListener("click" , function() {
   let result = document.getElementById("result");
  result.innerHTML = "Albenis.Kerqelis";
  result.style.width = "100%";
  result.style.minHeight = "40px";
  result.style.opacity = "1";
  result.innerHTML=(`Wow, you username is  ${user} and your password is ${pass.value}`);
  
})
```

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding:0;
  font-family:'Roboto' , sans-serif;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  margin:0;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
}

.flex {
width:250px;
 background-color:white;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);

  flex-flow:column wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  padding:30px;
  margin:40px 0;
  min-height:400px;
}

input {
 background-color:whitesmoke;
  color:black;
box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  border:none;
  padding:15px;
  margin:20px 0;
}



#result {
 width:0;
  background-color:springgreen;
  color:white;
  opacity:0;
  align-items:center;
  display:flex;
  font-weight:bold;
  transition:ease-in-out 1s;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
min-height:0;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex">
  <h1>Login form</h1>
    <input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="Type Your Username">
    <input type="password" id="text2" placeholder="Type Your Password">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Sign In</button>
    <span id="result"></span>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: You're accessing `pass.value` twice. Once in variable initialisation and another in the click callback.

Comment: i tried  to remove second value from "pass" but  still dont worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have some issues in your code.

- First of all, you get the value of your `user` and `password` element before the `onclick` event so by default they will be empty because the script will run once in the page load stage. So when you try to use their values they will be empty.
- You getting `undefined` because you trying to access the `password` value twice and since there is only one property named `value` in the password it will return `undefined`.

So your final code should be like this:

```js
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
const user = document.getElementById("text1");
const pass = document.getElementById("text2");

submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  result.style.width = "100%";
  result.style.minHeight = "40px";
  result.style.opacity = "1";
  result.innerHTML = (`Wow, you username is  ${user.value} and your password is ${pass.value}`);
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.flex {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 40px 0;
  min-height: 400px;
}

input {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#result {
  width: 0;
  background-color: springgreen;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: ease-in-out 1s;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 6px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  min-height: 0;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex">
    <h1>Login form</h1>
    <input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="Type Your Username">
    <input type="password" id="text2" placeholder="Type Your Password">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Sign In</button>
    <span id="result"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```